# navgationdrawer и вкладки

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

прошу совета. Сделал navgationdrawer на фрагментах, теперь нужно сделать вкладки, чтобы каждая вкладка указывала на фрагмент из списка меню, и при выборе пункта меню активная вкладка подсвечивалась. как это сделать подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: вы хотите одновременно и меню и вкладки сделать?

Comment: да, допустим захожу в меню выбираю пункт, перехожу на фрагмент там есть список вкладок и та вкладка которая соответствует странице чтобы была подсвечена

Comment: то есть у вас будет дублирование навигации?

Comment: получается что так, я сделал, но у меня страницы накладывались друг на друга, меню было задним фоном, а вкладки работали сами по себе по верх фрагментов меню

Comment: искал примеры, не где так и не нашел, то что мне нужно

Comment: вы знаете как сделать вкладки, или это тоже предстоит выяснять?

Comment: пока что затрудняюсь какой метод выбрать, у меня есть уже navgation drawer, а со вкладками как понимаю работает  ViewPager. поэтому не знаю в каком направлении идти, находил пример где делают вкладки и в navgation drawer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно будет реализовать двойную навигацию. То есть то что вы выбрали в боковом меню, то же будет и в табах. Все зависит от того как вы создавали ваше боковое меню, либо вам студия помогла либо вы сами все писали. В любом случае у вас будет xml файл или место в xml файле которое будет отвечать за вывод содержимого выбранного фрагмента, вот к примеру [сайт](https://medium.com/@cryptograph2013/navigation-drawer-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-android-java%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B-a4d881a04e78) на котором описано создание бокового меню, и тут есть разметка:

```
<!-- This DrawerLayout has two children at the root  -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Этот LinearLayout отображает содержимое экрана -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- ActionBar отображается сверху -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- Основной контентный view, куда загружаются фрагменты -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- navigation drawer, который появляется слева -->
    <!-- Обратите внимание, что `android:layout_gravity` нужно установить в 'start' -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

в этом куске:

```
 <!-- Этот LinearLayout отображает содержимое экрана -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- ActionBar отображается сверху -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- Основной контентный view, куда загружаются фрагменты -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

вам нужно отобразить здесь кроме `FrameLayout` еще и `TabLayout` в котором буду ваши вкладки. Либо если вам помогла студия в создании меню (это означает что вы изначально при создании проекта выбрали тип макета соответствующий боковому меню) то студия создает файлик xml который будет вам показывать содержимое вашего экрана, и там уже нужно будет размещать `TabLayout`.

И дальше все предельно просто: есть главный класс, в котором реализована логика работы с боковым меню, и есть разметка которая относится к боковому меню и контенту экрана. Вы при выборе пункта меню выбираете и таб который вам нужен. Это первый вариант, и он мне кажется более правильным по логике. Есть второй вариант - в каждом фрагменте влепить кроме всего прочего еще и `TabLayout` и отмечать нужный вам фрагмент посредством передачи через `bundle` какого-то идентификатора выбранного фрагмента. Но вы должны помнить что у вас два вида навигации, а значит вам нужно отмечать выбранный фрагмент уже в двух местах, чтобы не получилось так что выбран один фрагмент а индикация относится совсем к другому фрагменту.

P.S. Если кто-то заметит ошибку или неточность, буду рад если укажете на проблему :)

Comment: а можно как то это реализовать без TabLayout? Мне нужно размещать полосу прокрутки с табами в разных частях фрагмента. в каждом фрагменте расположение разное.

Comment: да можно, у меня в ответе приведен второй вариант решения, который вам нужен

Comment: то есть у меня щас есть куча готовых фрагментов, переключение свайпом и через navgationdrawer идет корректно, но нет табов в фрагментах, чтобы они появились нужно добавить в каждый фрагмент TabLayout. я правильно понимаю ?

Comment: если вам нужно размещение табов рандомное, то можно либо сделать условие для navigation_drawer где при выборе определенного фрагмента табы будут смещаться, либо разместить табы в каждом фрагменте и не заморачиваться

Comment: Может быть задам глупый вопрос, но я не где не могу найти ответ, сделал двойную навигацию с помощью navgationdrawer и viewpager теперь у меня есть табы и меню при переключении и свайпах все переключается корректно, могу размещать строку табов как мне нужно, но теперь не могу понять как заполнять фрагменты.

Comment: Делал по обрацу [ссылка](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/viewpager.php) переделал метод FragmentPagerAdapter в FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от вопроса. Если у вас появились дополнительные вопросы - вы их сможете задать нажав на кнопку "Задать вопрос" вверху страницы :)